# Why was lord Krishna driving Arjuna's chariot in Mahabharat war?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, arjuna

What is the significance and why lord Krishna driving Arjuna's chariot in Mahabharat war?

Comment: Strongly Related: [Why didn't Krishna take a more active part in Battle of Kurukshetra in Mahabharata?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/687/1049)

Comment: @Kailash Chandra Polai i think i have answered all of your queries do you want me to add something more in it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Truly he didn't fight on either on the side of Kaurvas or Pandavas he gave his celestial army (Akshauhini) to Duryodhana and became the charioteer of Arjuna without participating in the battle such is Lord's glory.

It is partially explained here:— [Why didn't Krishna take a more active part in Battle of Kurukshetra in Mahabharata?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/687/why-didnt-krishna-take-a-more-active-part-in-battle-of-kurukshetra-in-mahabhara)

but whole answer is here:—

> "Vaisampayana continued, 'Thus
>   addressed by Krishna, Dhananjaya
>   the son of Kunti selected Kesava who
>   was not to fight on the battle-field,
>   even Narayana himself, the slayer of
>   foes, increate, born among men at
>   his own will,--the foremost of all
>   Kshatriyas and above all the gods
>   and the Danavas . And Duryodhana
>   selected for himself that entire army
>   (composed of the Narayanas). And, O
>   descendant of Bharata, having
>   obtained those troops numbering
>   thousands upon thousands, he was
>   exceedingly delighted, although he
>   knew that Krishna was not on his
>   side. And having secured that army
>   possessed of terrible prowess,
>
> Duryodhana went
>   to the son of Rohini of great
>   strength, and explained to him, the
>   object of his visit. The descendant of
>   Sura in reply addressed the
>   following words to Dhritarashtra's
>   son, 'Thou shouldst remember, O
>   tiger among men, all that I said at
>   the marriage ceremony celebrated by
>   Vitrata. O thou delighter of the race
>   of Kuru, for thy sake I then
>   contradicted Krishna and spoke
>   against his opinions. And again and
>   again I alluded to the equality of
>   our relationship to both the parties.
>   But Krishna did not adopt the views
>   I then expressed; nor can I separate
>   myself from Krishna for even a single
>   moment. And seeing that I cannot
>   act against Krishna even this is
>   resolution formed by me, viz., that I
>   will fight neither for Kunti's sons nor
>   for you. And, O bull of the Bharatas,
>   born as thou art in Bharata's race
>   that is honoured by all the kings, go
>   and fight in accordance with the
>   rules of propriety.'
>
> "Vaisampayana continued, 'Thus
>   addressed, Duryodhana embraced
>   that hero wielding a plough for his
>   weapon of battle, and although
>   knowing that Krishna had been taken
>   away from his side, he yet regarded
>   Arjuna as already vanquished. And
>   the royal son of Dhritarashtra then
>   went to Kritavarman. And
>   Kritavarman gave him a body of
>   troops numbering an Akshauhini .
>   And surrounded by that military
>   host, terrible to behold, the Kaurava
>   marched forth delighting his friends.
>   And after Duryodhana had departed,
>   Krishna, the Creator of the world,
>   clad in yellow attire, addressed
>   Kiritin, saying, 'For what reason is it
>   that you have selected me who will
>   not fight at all?'
>
> "Thereupon Arjuna answered, 'I
>   question not that you are able to
>   slay them all. I also am alone
>   capable of slaying them, O best of
>   men. But you are an illustrious
>   person in the world; and this renown
>   will accompany you. I also am a
>   suitor for fame; therefore, you have
>   been selected by me. **It hath been
>   always my desire to have you for
>   driving my car. I, therefore, ask you
>   to fulfil my desire cherished for a
>   long time**.'
>
> **"Vasudeva's son thereupon said, It
>   beseems thee well, O Kunti's son,
>   that thou measurest thyself with me.
>   I will act as thy charioteer; let thy
>   wish be fulfilled.'**
>
> "Vaisampayana continued, 'Then
>   with a glad heart, Kunti's son,
>   accompanied by Krishna as well as
>   by the flower of the Dasarha race,
>   came back to Yudhishthira.'
>
> **—The Mahabharata, Book 5:
>   Udyoga Parva: SECTION VII**

source:— http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m05/m05007.htm

Comment: Nicely described, BTW did Krishna never used his Sudarshan chakra in the war? I listen only Sudarshan chakra was roaming around in the battle field and the armies were only for display purposes. It is true?

Comment: @Kailash Chandra Polai yes, sudarshana chakra was there in mahabharata but not that way what you are saying is in shanti parva where lord krishna as supreme being says that it is lord rudra that was killing everyone and others were instrument other than that this chapter mentions a war between nara-narayana and rudra during daksha yajna which i think is not universey accepted in any daksha sacrifice chapter and shanti parva is most interpolated book of mahabharata,

Comment: nara-narayana either performed peance at badrinath and got boon and that even shiva could not defeat them this is explained by vyasa telling why narayanastra did'nt worked on krishna and arjun while saving bhima from it.

Comment: About sudarshana chakra you can ask it in your question as it was used to make a fake sunset.