# How many Vyuhas were created in Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata, war, vyuha

How many Vyuhas were created in Mahabharata?

Who were the creators of the Vyuhas and who all knew how to destroy those Vyuhas?

I heard that 40 Vyuhas were created in Mahabharata like:

- Chakravyuha
- Kronchvyuha
- Garudvyuha
- ArdhChandrakarvyuha

I want to briefly know about who were the creators and destroyers of these Vyuhas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are some famous military formations and strategies used in Mahabharata war at Kurukshetra?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19423/what-are-some-famous-military-formations-and-strategies-used-in-mahabharata-war)